# Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream on mysql

Tags: mysql, windows, vb.net

I get this error when I publish the website on windows server 2003.

.Net framework version is 3.5. MySQL connector is 6.7.9.
I tried to add System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
to the global file in application_start

System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream. at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.StartSSL() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() at pcounter.report.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\aisied\Documents\Github\pcounter\pcounter\report.aspx.vb:line 20

Comment: Was the website developed on Windows XP, so that the capabilities are roughly equivalent to Windows Server 2003?

Comment: Any solution found for this? Running into an identical situation.

Answer (score -2):

Adding **sslmode=none** to connection string solved the problem.